# Manual Include in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following structure: `Training` has many `Module` has many `Phase` has many `Question`.

I use the following query to get the above

```
Context.Trainings
       .Include(x => x.Modules)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.Phases)
       .ThenInclude(y => y.Questions)
```

`Question` also has many `Comment` but that relationship is not defined as navigation property because `Comment` can have different type of patents. So `Comment` just has a `ParentId` that is sometimes `Question` and sometimes other things.

My question is how do I modify the above query to, for every `Question`, count the child `Comment` from the `Context.Comments` and assign it to `Question.CommentCount`? Kind of like a manual `Include`

In my head it's something like this

```
Context.Trainings
       .Include(x => x.Modules)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.Phases)
       .ThenInclude(y => y.Questions.Select(x=> new Question.Question {              
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description,                
                CommentCount = Context.Comments.Where(y=>y.ParentId == x.Id)                
            }));
```

But it seems you can't put projections in `Include` and I don't know how to think about this in another way.

Comment: You can do that part in projection ? That is what I missing in above query. How you select data you required.

Comment: If you need custom calculations, You have to use `Select`. Which DTO classes you are trying to generate?

Comment: @dotnetstep  abovequery.`ToListAsync()` All the data above is required so there no need to use projections to select data manually. So I tend to not use them, though I suspect that's what's needed here I am just no sure how.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I am generating all the classes in the above hierarchy with that query. The question is specifically about how to do a special calculation on the `Questions` level of the hierarchy.

Comment: You should still define the navigation in EF Core, even if you can't create a FK in the database. Also you could define `Comment` as a TPH, with a generic navigation property so the relationship works both ways.

Comment: Also, you should consider flipping the query to `Context.Questions.Select(q => new { Question = q, Phase = q.Phase, Module = q.Phase.Module, Training = ..., })`

Comment: Having calculated properties in entity classes is something EF is dearly missing. You either have to use a database view or project to DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

With the entities set up such as ...

```cs
public class Training
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
}

public class Phase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int CommentCount { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

// DbContext
public DbSet<Training> Trainings { get; set; }
public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

... it can be done in a single query, but it's quite messy.

```cs
// query all nested navigations using projections with extra data
var projected = await context.Trainings
    .Select(t => 
        new 
        { 
            Training = t, 
            Modules = t.Modules.Select(m => 
                new 
                { 
                    Module = m, 
                    Phases = m.Phases.Select(p => 
                        new 
                        { 
                            Phase = p, 
                            Questions = p.Questions.Select(q => 
                                new 
                                { 
                                    Question = q, 
                                    CommentCount = context.Comments.Count(c => c.ParentId == q.Id) 
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
    .ToListAsync();

// fixup by setting comment count from dto projection to "real" tracked entity
foreach (var q in projected.SelectMany(t => t.Modules).SelectMany(m => m.Phases).SelectMany(m => m.Questions))
{
    q.Question.CommentCount = q.CommentCount;
}

// thanks to ef core entity tracker this will still work
var trainings = projected.Select(p => p.Training);
var totalCommentCount = trainings.SelectMany(t => t.Modules).SelectMany(m => m.Phases).SelectMany(p => p.Questions).Sum(q => q.CommentCount);
```

final query

```sql
SELECT [t].[Id], [t0].[Id], [t0].[TrainingId], [t0].[Id0], [t0].[ModuleId], [t0].[Id00], [t0].[PhaseId], [t0].[c]
      FROM [Trainings] AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[TrainingId], [t1].[Id] AS [Id0], [t1].[ModuleId], [t1].[Id0] AS [Id00], [t1].[PhaseId], [t1].[c]
          FROM [Modules] AS [m]
          LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[ModuleId], [q].[Id] AS [Id0], [q].[PhaseId], (
                  SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM [Comments] AS [c]
                  WHERE [c].[ParentId] = [q].[Id]) AS [c]
              FROM [Phases] AS [p]
              LEFT JOIN [Questions] AS [q] ON [p].[Id] = [q].[PhaseId]
          ) AS [t1] ON [m].[Id] = [t1].[ModuleId]
      ) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[TrainingId]
      ORDER BY [t].[Id], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Id0]
```

As pointed out in comments, you could benefit from using TPH with real navigation collection back to comments from questions, and you should also probably use split query or multiple queries instead of joining it all up like this. But depending on use case, perhaps a single query might perform better for you.